# "Но ведь... и ведь", - забыла правило про запятые

Tags: пунктуация

> Пусть для современников Христос существовал повсюду и церковь не была
>   его резиденцией или местом вынесения приговора, но ведь не Христос, а
>   епископ занимал почётное место на троне, и ведь не Христу приносилась
>   здесь жертва – она освящалась для верующих.

Запятая перед "и ведь"...

У нас что - ССП? "Христос/епископ занимал", "жертва приносилась"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, здесь сложное предложение с разными видами сочинительной, подчинительной и бессоюзной связи.

К двум простым, связанным сочинительным союзом И, относятся два однородных уступительных придаточных (Пусть для современников Христос существовал повсюду и церковь не была его резиденцией или местом вынесения приговора). Поэтому между ЭТИМИ придаточными не ставим запятую.

Но только ВТОРОМУ простому предложению (ведь не Христу приносилась здесь жертва) противопоставлено последнее простое (она освящалась для верующих). Поэтому после "троне" стоит запятая.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, здесь ССП, а общее только *но*, это вынуждает ставить запятую.

Comment: Но "но" противопоставлено (или ссимметричено) "и".